# Inheritance in huge DTOs

Tags: api, rest, inheritance, dto

I have two applications, namely *A* and *B*.

*A* calls a rest API from *B* and passes a huge dto with 46 field in the body. I need all that data in application *B*. But as a new requirement, I must add 4 more field to this dto in order to handle another kind of request that needs all the other 46 fields.
I managed it by using inheritance concept. Now I have 2 rest APIs to handle each type and there are some places where I have to use condition on type of the objects to avoid duplication.
I thought I was preserving single responsibility principal.

But I wonder if it's the right way to have 2 rest APIs for such matter since it propagates complexity to client. Is it better to have a flat object and a single API?

And if inheritance is a good solution? (Because of duplications and conditions on type of objects).

And, is this OK to have such a huge dto and pass it around? Is there anyway I could avoid it?

Comment: This is too opinion based for this site, it might fit better on the Software Engineering stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you confuse REST APIs with endpoints, or the question does not make much sense. Having two endpoints for 2 operations e.g. `POST /B/v1/x1 {body1}` and `POST /B/v1/x2 {body1+4fields}` is totally ok. Posting two different request bodies to the same endpoint can be ok too if they do almost the same thing `POST /B/v1/x1 {body1}` vs `POST /B/v1/x1 {body1+4fields}`. As of DTO inheritance I prefer splitting it up to smaller DTOs and have a bigger DTO which is a composite of the smaller ones `{p:{p1,p2,p3,...}, q: {q1,q2,q3,...}, f:{f1,f2,f3,f4}}`. With this approach your additional 4 fields `f` can be optional. Generally speaking we avoid inheritance and follow to composition over inheritance principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance